# How to reset query cursor in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cursor

My code fetches results from the datastore in batches, and detecs when it reaches the end. How do I actually reset, or remove, the cursor, so that the next time, I start at the beginning of the query?

```
q = Company.all()
q.order("datetime")

company_cursor = memcache.get("company_cursor")

if company_cursor:
    q.with_cursor(start_cursor = company_cursor)

chunk_size = 5
companies = q.fetch(chunk_size)

for company in companies: 
    do_stuff(company)

if len(companies) < chunk_size:
    # This is where I want to reset, or remove, the cursor.
    memcache.add("company_cursor",company_cursor, 11000) # 10800 == 180 min.

company_cursor = q.cursor() 
memcache.set("company_cursor",company_cursor, 11000)
```

Comment: YOu should include how you are calling this set of code ?  Why do you store company_cursor in memcache ?  (cursors are designed that they can be encoded in the url and passed back and forth.  By using a fixed key 'company_cursor' if you have concurrent queries you will end up with a mixed up state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GAE you can just stop using the cursor.

So in your case, you'd just clear the cursor out of memcache, and you should be ok.

Comment: so, memcache.delete("company_cursor") would do the trick? it does not seem to work, though.

Comment: that should work.  you might want to check that you're not setting the cursor elsewhere.